# An extra blank page in the document

Tags: titles, blank-page

the following code inserts an extra blank front page in my document though I have not even mentioned any title or whatsoever. Please guide me where am I going wrong. Thanks In advance.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\chapter*{TITLE}
\section*{\texttt{NAME and ID}}
\section*{ \emph{Supervisor}}
\textbf{\textsf{DISSERTATION INITIAL DRAFT}}
\end{center}
\section*{Description}
\section*{Summary}
\begin{thebibliography}{x}
\bibitem{easley} David Easley, Jon Kleinberg. \emph{Networks, Crowds and Markets: Reasoning about a Highly Connected World}, Cambridge University Press, 2010
\bibitem{macy} Damon Centola, Michael Macy. \emph{Complex Contagion and the Weakness of Long Ties}, American Journal of Sociology, 2007
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

I am using TexMaker if that helps :)

Comment: please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The use of `\chapter` inside the `center` environment produces the extra page(s). If you want to create a title, it's better not to use the sectional unit commands. You can do it yourself by hand or using a dedicated package such as [`titling`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titling); a little example:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\Huge\bfseries TITLE\par\bigskip}
{\Large\ttfamily NAME and ID\par\medskip}
{\Large\itshape\bfseries Supervisor\par\medskip}
{\bfseries\sffamily DISSERTATION INITIAL DRAFT\par\bigskip}
\end{center}

\section*{Description}
\section*{Summary}
\begin{thebibliography}{x}
\bibitem{easley} David Easley, Jon Kleinberg. \emph{Networks, Crowds and Markets: Reasoning about a Highly Connected World}, Cambridge University Press, 2010
\bibitem{macy} Damon Centola, Michael Macy. \emph{Complex Contagion and the Weakness of Long Ties}, American Journal of Sociology, 2007
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Since, apparently, no major sectional units are required (i.e, the document don't require chapters starting on a page of their own), it's better to switch to the `article` document class; here's an example using `article` and the `titling` package to produce the title:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titling}

\pretitle{\begin{center}\Huge\bfseries}
\posttitle{\par\end{center}\vskip 0.5em}
\preauthor{\begin{center}\Large\ttfamily}
\postauthor{\par{\Large\itshape\bfseries
Supervisor\par\medskip}{\bfseries\sffamily DISSERTATION INITIAL DRAFT}\end{center}}
\predate{\par\large}
\postdate{\par}

\title{TITLE}
\author{NAME and ID}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section*{Description}
\section*{Summary}
\begin{thebibliography}{x}
\bibitem{easley} David Easley, Jon Kleinberg. \emph{Networks, Crowds and Markets: Reasoning about a Highly Connected World}, Cambridge University Press, 2010
\bibitem{macy} Damon Centola, Michael Macy. \emph{Complex Contagion and the Weakness of Long Ties}, American Journal of Sociology, 2007
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As can be seen, it's more economical (in this simple case) to build the title manually.

Answer (score 6):

Since you are using the `book` class, you probably want the first page of your document to be a cover page.

For this purpose, the `book` class provides a `titlepage` environment where you can insert all the stuff which has to go in the cover page. At the end of that environment a new page is started.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\centering
\vspace*{1in}
{\Huge\bfseries TITLE\par}
\vspace*{0.75in}
{\Large\ttfamily NAME and ID\par}
\medskip
{\Large\itshape\bfseries Supervisor\par}
\medskip
{\bfseries\sffamily DISSERTATION INITIAL DRAFT\par}
\end{titlepage}

\section*{Description}
\section*{Summary}
\begin{thebibliography}{x}
\bibitem{easley} David Easley, Jon Kleinberg. \emph{Networks, Crowds and Markets: Reasoning about a Highly Connected World}, Cambridge University Press, 2010
\bibitem{macy} Damon Centola, Michael Macy. \emph{Complex Contagion and the Weakness of Long Ties}, American Journal of Sociology, 2007
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Also my bibliography goes on a separate page how to bring it on the same page as the two sections?

Comment: @Abi Why are you using `book`? Use `\documentclass{article}` instead.